# CSS - Hide elements (class) based on value of select box

Tags: html, css

I have a `<select>` box in a `<form>`, and when its value is `other`, I want elements that have the class `.applicableSupportCase` to be hidden. I am trying to do this with just CSS. What am I doing wrong?

### CSS

```
.applicableSupportCase  {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
}
#typeBox[value="other"] ~ .applicableSupportCase{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

### HTML

```
<select class="contactField" id="typeBox">
  <option value="supportCase" selected="selected">Support case</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<label class="applicableSupportCase">Device:</label>
```

There are more elements with the `applicableSupportCase` class, but you get the point.

Comment: could you please add your html markup?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with `<select>` items. With checkboxes, and radio buttons you can because they have multiple states (clicked vs un-clicked) that can be accessed using only css. With a select you can't ask which item is selected because css doesn't really care...

Comment: Why not use `display` or `visibility` css properties to hide it?

Comment: @PrestonS The issue doesn't seem to be the css attribute used to hide the class. I think Logan is looking for a method to use the value chosen from the select box as a cue to do a certain action.

Comment: @Enigmadan Exactly. When a specific `<option>` is selected, some things should be hidden. It's part of a form, and `.applicableSupportCase` elements only should be shown when the other `<option>` is chosen.

Comment: @Enigmadan I understand that.  I'm just wondering why opacity is being used when there are more appropriate options.  The point is moot though as it can't be done with pure CSS.  If JS was used though I would recommend using one of the CSS properties I mention above.

Comment: Just for animation. I will add `display: none;` after I finish this.

Comment: @PrestonS Ok. I completely agree with you on the select issue (and the css properties that should be used). However, it would be possible with pure css if, instead of a select, you used radio buttons.

Comment: @Enigmadan Ok. How could I do this then? Could you add an answer?

Comment: @PhoenixLogan, check my updated answer for a simple JS solution...

Comment: Give me a moment, I'll have a fiddle for you.

Comment: Added my answer. If you really want a css-only solution, then radio boxes are the way to go.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan Would radio buttons work for your application?

Comment: @Enigmadan Possibly. It's mostly just design that is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done using a `<select>` item, however because of the pseudo class `:checked` states of checkboxes and radio buttons, you can accomplish what you wanted using those instead:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="supportCase" name="radios"> 
<label for="supportCase">Support Case</label>
<input type="radio" id="other" name="radios"> 
<label for="other">Other</label>
    <br />
<label class="applicableSupportCase">Device:</label>
```

CSS

```
input[id=other]:checked ~ .applicableSupportCase {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

I used visibility, but you can change the attribute to whatever you want.

If you want an ease in and out, then create the same statement using the `:not(:checked)` pseudo class:

```
input[id=other]:not(:checked) ~ .applicableSupportCase {
  //whatever ease(out) you want here
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ja2ud1Lf/

Comment: It's not actually *because of the pseudos*. The `select` has the same pseudos. The point is that radio inputs stay at the same node level as the label. That makes it a sibling. The `option` however is nested to the `select` so there's no possible selector.

Comment: @LcSalazar Interesting. Thanks for explaining that! 
However, in that case, when would the `:checked` pseudo for a `select` occur? Does it have to do with the `selected="selected"` or something else?

Comment: I'm also curious as to why I was downvoted. Does my answer have any incorrect information I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the css attribute selector don't look at value in the way that you are thinking...

Though Javascript sees the `value` property as the selected option's value, CSS sees only the markup, and an `select[value='something']` attribute selector would actually look for this:

```
<select value='something'>
```

Not for the `<option>` selected.

Through css-only you will not be able to change another element using the selected option because the `<option>` is nested to the `<select>` tag, and there's no parent navigation selection on css.

**EDIT**

You can, however, mock it up with javascript, and leave your css selector as it is. Just trigger the select's onchange event to set an attribute called `value` to the DOM select element:

[**See Working Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qe2quzx1/1/)

```
document.getElementById('typeBox').onchange = function() {
    this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
};
```

Comment: I'm really against using JavaScript for this... I'm trying to do it with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use personally create another class for hidden objects (eg 'hiddenClass'), and use jquery similar to the following:

```
$( "#typeBox" ).change(function(){
 if($("#typeBox").val()=="other")
 {
     $(".applicableSupportCase").each(function(){
         $(this).addClass("hiddenClass");
     });
 }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Javascript/jQuery specifically and use only CSS.